# large number of dummy variables in deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dummy-variable

I am trying to train a deep learning model for a regression problem. I have 2000 significant categorical inputs each of which has 3 categories. If I convert them to dummy variables, then I will have 6,000 dummy variables as input to deep learning model and it makes optimization very hard since my inputs (6,000 dummy variables) are not zero centered. Also, variance in each dummy variable is small so 6,000 dummy variables will have a hard time to explain variance in output. I was wondering if I need to use z score for dummy variables to help optimization? Also, is there a better solution to deal with these 2,000 categorical inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Embeddings](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding), which translates large sparse vectors into a lower-dimensional space that preserves semantic relationships. So for each categorical feature, you will have dense vector representation.

Here is pseudocode using TensorFlow:

```
unique_amount_1 = np.unique(col1)
input_1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='input_1')
embedding_1 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(unique_amount_1, 50, trainable=True)(input_1)
col1_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(embedding_1)

unique_amount_2 = np.unique(col2)
input_2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='input_2')
embedding_2 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(unique_amount_2, 50, trainable=True)(input_2)
col2_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(embedding_2)

combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([col1_embedding, col2_embedding])
result = tf.keras.layers.Dense()(combined)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[col1, col2], outputs=result)
```

Where `50` - the size of the embedding vector.

Comment: Thanks. So, if my pandas data frame has 100,000 rows and 2,000 columns (I have 2,000 categorical variables each of which takes 3 values (0,1,2)) then 1- what would be shape of data after embedding layer? 2- what should be size of the embedding vector? 3- how can I make sure my data after embedding layer is zero centered to solve an easier optimization problem?